# Unintuitive behavior (to me) in Reactive.jl

Tags: julia, reactive-programming

My question relates to the Reactive package https://github.com/JuliaLang/Reactive.jl

I have read the [tutorial](http://julialang.org/Reactive.jl/) and am experimenting, learning about the reactive programming approach. I try the following code and it works as expected:

```
using Reactive

x = Signal(100)
z = map(v -> v + 500, x; typ=Int64, init=500)
dar = rand(90:110,10)

for i in dar
    push!(x, i)
    println(value(z))
end
```

This leads, as expected, to 10 random numbers betwwen 590 and 610 being printed:

```
500
591
609
609
605
593
602
596
590
594
```

So far, so good. Now, suppose I want to collect the outputs of signal z after each update, say in a vector c:

```
using Reactive

x = Signal(100)
z = map(v -> v + 500, x; typ=Int64, init=500)
dar = rand(90:110,10)
c = Vector()

for i in dar
    push!(x, i)
    push!(c, value(z))
end
```

However, instead of Vector c having ten random numbers between 590 and 610, c is a Vector containing the value 500 ten times:

```
10-element Array{Any,1}:
500
500
500
500
500
500
500
500
500
500
```

I am trying to understand if this behavior is caused by something I don't understand about Reactive programming; maybe combining *for loops* and *Signals* is a no-no? I would appreciate any insight into what is causing this behavior.

For reference, I am using Julia 0.4.5 inside an IJulia notebook.

Comment: It's not an answer, but adding `yield()` between `push!`s is a minimal change which makes things work. The update of `z`'s value happens in another task.

Comment: Instead of `yield()`, use `Reactive.run_till_now()` after the `push!` to the signal. This tip is from https://github.com/JuliaLang/Reactive.jl/issues/99

Comment: That does work, thank you. This doesn't seem like it should happen like this, but that makes more sense.

Comment: Don't know why this was downvoted, seems like a perfectly good question to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Julia's [Reactive.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLang/Reactive.jl) library is designed to allow [Reactive programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_programming) in Julia. The crux is that only signal are reactive, and they are either independent or dependent on other signals. In the example, `x` is an independent signal, and the default update to the signal will call `push!`. `z` is dependent signal on `x`, which is why it gets automatically updated when `x` changes.

Now, these are the only two signals, notice that `c` is defined to be `Vector()`, which is not a signal but a normal array in Julia. So any code that runs on it only performs once like all non-reactive languages. Therefore

```
for i in dar
    push!(x, i)
    push!(c, value(z))
end
```

will only allocate to `c` once, when the code is first run, whereby `z` still holds its default value of `500` due to `init=500` in the code. This make intuitive sense. In fact, if `c` is changed due to `z`, then we have made the underlying behaviour of Julia to be reactive, and this is volatile and so is undesirable...

So how do we make `c` update whenever `z` does? The correct way is to use Reactive programming all the way, and so `c` should be a dependent signal of `z`. Since `c` maintains the state of `z`, the correct construct in Reactive programming is `foldp`, which stands for "fold over past values".

A code that works is the following:-

```
using Reactive

x = Signal(100)
z = map(v -> v + 500, x)
c = foldp((acc, value) -> push!(acc, value), Int[], z)

for i in rand(90:110, 10)
    push!(x, i)
    yield() #Can also use Reactive.run_till_now()
    println(value(z))
end

@show value(c)
```

You will get `c` to be the array of all previous values of `z` (except the initial value by choice, so if you want the initial value too that can be easily done). Notice that Reactive programming retains a similar code complexity, but adds in the reactive capability. This make the code more elegant and easier to maintain.

Using `yield()` or `Reactive.run_till_now()` is as recommended in the comment, so I shall skim on the explanation. But my opinion is that if you need to do that, then you are likely not using reactive programming correctly, or your problem will fit other paradigm better.

This is how I would write:-

```
using Reactive

x = Signal(100)

z = map(x) do v
    result = v + 500
    println(result)
    return result
end

c = foldp(Int[], z) do acc, value
    push!(acc, value)
end

for i in rand(90:110, 10)
    push!(x, i)
end

@show value(c)
```

Notice that the reactive part is self describing. Now `z` prints itself whenever it is updated, which is descriptive instead of imperative. So even though update is async, we will still capture an update to `z`. The imperative code of pushing to `x` is by itself, keeping things modular. The code is high level enough and easy to read, without low level routine passing functions like `yield()` inside such a high level script.

Comment: Thank you @ShaoWei for your detailed and informative reply. Appreciate you taking the time to explain so thoroughly.

Comment: You are welcome @pyrex, Reactive.jl on Julia is quite beautiful and it is a pleasure to share about that with you.